# Honesty time, is working with other users to get a hat considered cheating?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

Let's say, I agreed with other users on one of SE sites to get a hat, for example the (5 answers in 30 minutes hat), each one of us will ask a question and the other five will answer quickly and so on, we all get the hats and all are happy..

**Is this considered cheating?** Please note we will ask real questions and answer real answers, we won't delete the answers and then the question at a later time. Of course the answers might be redundant, but the traffic in some SE sites are not as much as the traffic in SO or SU and that's the only way to get it.

Little history, I have done a similar thing in the past to get a hat, and I do not feel that great about it. So I kinda need to clear this.

Comment: I agree with you. There are some hats that promote bad behavior.

Answer (score 8):

When it's Winter Bash, normal rules apply.

This means that you are not allowed to post nonsense just to get the hat. It's no problem to post a question for the hat, *as long as the question is high-quality and useful for future visitors*. You said that the questions were real questions, so I think it's no problem here.

The same counts for answers; they should be high-quality and useful. If all answers are useful, that's nice. I don't know how exactly the answers are redundant, but if that means they are all the same, I'm not a huge fan. It would be no problem though if all answers were different.